# Add css class to all uncheked radio button's labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of radio buttons with labels :

```html
<input id="angry[1]" type="radio" name="emotion-rate-q1" value="angry" required="required" />
<label class="radio-score angry" for="angry[1]">1</label>
<input id="bad[1]" type="radio" name="emotion-rate-q1" value="bad" />
<label class="radio-score bad" for="bad[1]">2</label>
<input id="neutral[1]" type="radio" name="emotion-rate-q1" value="neutral" />
<label class="radio-score neutral" for="neutral[1]">3</label>
<input id="happy[1]" type="radio" name="emotion-rate-q1" value="happy" />
<label class="radio-score happy" for="happy[1]">4</label>
<input id="fantastic[1]" type="radio" name="emotion-rate-q1" value="fantastic" />
<label class="radio-score fantastic" for="fantastic[1]">5</label>
```

In javascript (or jquery ) I want that when I click on of these button, it apply to all the others button's labels a css class (so with tis new css class I will apply some style to the unchecked buttons)

Comment: `input:not(:checked) + label { /* format me as if I was special baby */ }`

Comment: @CBroe Do not answer questions in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way.

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  $("label").removeClass("active");
  $("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

It will add class `active` to selected radio button's label. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/9a58ar6u/3/)

### Update

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
 $("label").removeClass("active");
 $("label").not("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").addClass("active");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/9a58ar6u/5/)

Comment: I need to add a class to all the unselected radio button label, not the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the solution by below approach.

```
 // 1. by using CSS3 
    input:not(:checked) + label {background:red }

// 2. by using jquery 
   if($('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)')){
   $('label').addClass("active")
   }
```